# How to use BingMaps with Aurelia

Tags: typescript, webpack, bing-maps, aurelia

I am using aurelia skeleton typescript webpack template for my app.
I want to add BingMaps to a page and be able to add pushpins etc.
So far I've done this:

> index.html - I added a script tag that loads the map from CDN

```
<head>
...
   <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'></script>
</head>
```

then I added a template like this:

> map.html

```
<template>
   <div id='mainMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
</template>
```

then I have the map controller:

> map.ts

```
export class Map {

    private map: Microsoft.Map.Map;

    attached() {
        this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('mainMap', { credentials:'mycredentials - omitted'});
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, if I start the application the welcome screent (from the skeleton) is displayed. Then I click on the 'Map' menu link and the map page is show with the map fully loaded.
But if I click refresh in browser (F5 or Ctrl+F5) the map is not show anymore and an error is displayed in the console:

> bluebird.js:1546 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
>       at k (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:7096)
>       at h (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:6285)
>       at e (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:1106)
>       at t.l [as instance] (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:161)
>       at h (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:6042)
>       at e (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:1106)
>       at t.l [as instance] (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:11:161)
>       at new Microsoft.Maps.Map (https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol:13:4304)
>       at Map.attached (http://localhost:9000/app.bundle.js:31267:20)
>       at Controller.attached (http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:6438:22)
>       at View.attached (http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:4524:23)
>       at ViewSlot.attached (http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:4883:13)
>       at View.attached (http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:4534:19)
>       at ViewSlot.attached (http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:4883:13)
>       at http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:14717:28

This error is thrown when it is trying to instantiate the Map object in the Attached event of the map controller.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this issue is to use the `callback` parameter that the API allows us to specify in the script url.  I've created a custom element to do this. The script is loaded when the module is initially loaded. Any instances of the custom element will wait for the callback function to be called. I originally was using a convoluted setup with a `MutationObserver` and data attributes, but after to talking to Jeremy Danyow, he pointed out that "Promisifying" the callback will solve the solution much more simply. This simpler solution is shown below.

The custom element currently doesn't offer any API for interacting with the map, other than getting the current center point of the map, but it's a good starting point to help you.

**bing-map.ts**

```ts
import { bindable, bindingMode, inlineView } from 'aurelia-framework';

const controlUrl = '//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=bingMapsLoaded';
const ready = new Promise(resolve => window['bingMapsLoaded'] = resolve);

let scriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement('script');

scriptTag.async = true;
scriptTag.defer = true;
scriptTag.src = controlUrl;

document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

@inlineView('<template><div ref="container" css="width: ${width}; height: ${height};"></div></template>')
export class BingMapCustomElement {
  private container: HTMLElement;
  private map: Microsoft.Maps.Map;
  private viewChangeHandler: Microsoft.Maps.IHandlerId;

  @bindable apiKey = '';
  @bindable height = '600px';
  @bindable width = '400px';

  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) location: Microsoft.Maps.Location | string;

  attached() {
    return ready.then(() => {
      this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.container as HTMLElement, {
        credentials: this.apiKey
      });

      this.location = this.map.getCenter();

      this.viewChangeHandler = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.map, 'viewchange', e => {
        this.location = this.map.getCenter();
      });
    });
  }

  detached() {
    if (this.viewChangeHandler) {
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(this.viewChangeHandler);
    }

    if (this.map) {
      this.map.dispose();
      this.map = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
<bing-map api-key.bind="mapsApiKey" width="100px" height="100px"></bing-map>
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution and is more reusable than my solution, which is a great Aurelia approach! @Luka, I think you should try this method.

Comment: Thanks @LStarky! Just know I wasn't trying to say bad things about the solutions you posted, I was just pointing out that they still suffer from the timing issue. It took me a while to figure out the timing issue. :-)

Comment: The important thing I was going for with my answer was to get something that will work even if a dev wants to put more than one map on the page or wants to use a map in different places in their app. But man, did I go down a crazy route with the mutation observer. But hey, I learned how to work with that API, so it wasn't a complete waste of time :-)

Comment: No worries, I'm interested in the best answer too! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Ashley. That works well and is a nice encapsulated solution. I like it. The only problem I have is the api-key binding. If i write api-key.bind=, the value is 0. But if i write api-key=, the value is the true key.

Comment: @Luka that's very strange. I'm using `api-key.bind="mapsApiKey"` in the test app I wrote to work on this. The `attached` callback happens after binding has occurred, so it should be set. I just have `mapsApiKey` set as a hardcoded property on the VM of the page using the custom element, so it's possible you have something else in your code that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to instantiate the map before the external script has fully loaded.  It works in your first scenario but doesn't work when you do a direct refresh.

**There's a great solution posted here:**

[How to wait BingMaps to be loaded in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906424/how-to-wait-bingmaps-to-be-loaded-in-aurelia)

The problem with the callback solution is that you're loading the external script in index.html, which is blind to whether or not you're currently wanting to display a map.  So the second solution is more appropriate.  However, I think the solution was written for ESNext code and you're using TypeScript, which means that the typeof properties are never going to be undefined.  The following code for **map.ts** would work better in your context (you might have to debug it a little since I wasn't able to test it):

```
export class Map
{
  map:Microsoft.Maps.Map;

  attached() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    if ((Microsoft == null) || (Microsoft.Maps == null)) {
      // not yet available, keep trying (dirty checking)
      setTimeout(this.loadMap, 100);
    } else {
      // Map API available; proceed to render the map
      this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#mainMap', {credentials: myKey});
      this.map.setView({center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.093,14.114), zoom:15});
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `if ((Microsoft == null) || (Microsoft.Maps == null))` test instead of the `undefined` test.

**Another great solution (by Jason Sobell)**

http://www.sobell.net/calling-external-javascript-from-within-aurelia-templates/

**A third great solution (after some callback research)**

You can implement this *without* the external script link in `index.html`, since this should provide the loading mechanism dynamically.

```
export class Map
{
  private map: any;

  attached() {
    this.loadScript("//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?onload=callback");
  }

  loadScript(sScriptSrc) {
    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement('script');
    oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
    oScript.onload = this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    // Map API available; proceed to render the map
    this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#mainMap', {credentials: myKey});
    this.map.setView({center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.093,14.114), zoom:15});
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. That was my question on stackoverflow. The problem is that the loadMap function throws the same exception. And if(typeof Microsoft !== undefined && typeof Microsoft.Maps !== undefined) it always true so the script appears to be loaded.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you were the same person. I'll look at it more when I get to work in an hour.

Comment: Did you try to implement the callback function?  That definitely seems like the cleanest solution and doesn't require the undefined check above.  I'll try to give a more complete solution above.

Comment: The problem with callback function is that I don't know how to do this callback function. I mean I know how to do it in index.html but then how will my map.ts know about that function

Comment: I agree that the callback function is hard to implement in this particular context.  I just updated my response above with something that I think should work.  I'm also willing to further develop the second "Jason Sobell" solution if needed.

Comment: Ok, I tried your updated response. The same error is thrown. If i put a breakpoint on the if statement, Microsoft is not null and Microsoft.Maps != null too. They are object. typeof(Microsoft) == 'object'.

Comment: Also I don't know how to use the  Jason Sobell's scriptinjector.

Comment: If they're evaluating as objects, it would seem that the script has already loaded.  I've never used Bing maps... are you sure you're instantiating it correctly with `this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#mainMap', {credentials: myKey});`?

Comment: Yes, cause the maps load correctly if I don't refresh the page They only break if i refresh the browser (F5 or Ctrl+F5)

Comment: I'm working on another solution.  But in the meantime, try just changing the third line from `map:Microsoft.Maps.Map;` to `map:any;`

Comment: @LStarky check out the answer I've posted. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @AshleyGrant.  And I also posted my third solution.  Luka, hopefully you can figure it out between these solutions!

Comment: I originally wrote my solution using the `onload` callback of the script tag, but it doesn't work in all cases. The problem is that the API isn't fully ready until some initialization code has run. That's why I defined a callback on the window object for the bing code to call when it was finished loading.

Comment: I've updated my solution to use promises instead of `MutationObserver` based on advice from Jeremy Danyow. Check it out below, it doesn't suffer from the timing issues that the solutions @LStarky has provided.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try it at once the report back.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LStarky, i choose Ashley solution because it is more encapsulated.